# Is my logic valid for this probability function?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification

You have to form a group of r people. In your class, there are $m$ men, $w$ women
and $n$ non-binary individuals. Suppose a group is selected uniformly at random, and
assume  $m, w, n ≥ r ≥ 5$. Find a closed-form probability function $f(x)$ which provides the probability that a given group has $x$ women, and $x + 5$ non-binary individuals.

Here, since no information is given about the presence of men in the group, I am assuming that there are no men in this group or does this question implicitly imply that there are men too in the group? My probability function is:
$$f(x)=\frac{{{\binom{w}{x}}}{{\binom{n}{x+5}}}}{{\binom{m+w+n}{r}}}$$
$$=\frac{{w! \cdot n! \cdot r! (m+w+n-r)!}}{{x! (w-x)! (x+5)! (n-x-5)! (m+w+n)!}}$$

Comment: If there are $r$ people total, and $x$ women and $x+5$ non binary, how many men are there in the group?

Comment: If I were to take men into account this would be my expression: $\binom{m}{r-x-x-5}$ but that's the thing, the question does not explicitly talk about men being in the group

Comment: In situations like this where you're not sure,  try small cases. If $ r = 4,  x = 1$, does your $f(x)$ match what you expect?

Comment: The constraint is $m,w,n≥r≥5$

Comment: Sure, take $ r = 8, x = 1$ then.

Comment: Okay, I am getting a valid value but again, if I include or not include men, I will still technically get a valid probability. I am only not sure if I have to include men or not.

Comment: It's not about getting a "valid probability" (which I presume you mean is between 0 and 1). Did you get the right probability?

Comment: Oh okay, I figured it out, thanks for your help!